# How do I hide menus without a layer file in NetBeans Platform?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins, netbeans-platform

I am having a hard time customizing my menus in the NetBeans Platform. The examples I've seen require you to have a Layer file which I don't believe I have in my NetBeans Platform Project.

To hide a menu via layers you are supposed to do this:

```
<folder name="Menu">
  <folder name="View_hidden"/>
  <folder name="Edit">
    <file name="org-openide-actions-FindAction.shadow_hidden"/>
  </folder>
</folder>
```

I would like to know the annotation way of hiding menus. However, if this is the only way to do it, where would I put the layer file and what would i name it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to hide menu items is to add the entries to your layer file. To add a layer file to your module you'll need to

1. Create a new xml file called `layer.xml` in any package in your module
2. Register the new layer file in your Module Manifest file (under the Important Files node) using the following pattern `OpenIDE-Module-Layer: com/example/layer.xml` where `com/example` is the package that you created the layer file in

In the layer.xml file you'll need to start with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE filesystem PUBLIC "-//NetBeans//DTD Filesystem 1.2//EN" "http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/filesystem-1_2.dtd">
<filesystem>
</filesystem>
```

**Shortcut for adding the _hidden nodes**

Once you've added a layer file to your module you can get NetBeans to add the necessary `_hidden` nodes by:

1. Expand the **Important Files** node in your module (any module will do but if/when this module is uninstalled then the layer file is also uninstalled)
2. Expand the **XML Layer** node (this is added once you've manually added the layer.xml file as above)
3. Expand the **this layer in context** node
4. Expand the **Menu Bar** node
5. Right click the **menu item** you want to hide and select Delete